# Adderall on Hair Drug Test (Dosage)?

Tags: drug-test

I am prescribed 10mg Adderall 2x a day, I take mostly on weekdays to help me with my job, sometimes i may take an extra one but i do not take on weekends/holiday/time off. I just got a new dream job and they will be doing hair test. I do have a prescription so that would not be an issue, and it would not be considered a safety risk since it is sales, my question would be: I know it will come as positive for Amphetamine, will they see that sometimes i may take more than the prescribed? Does the hair test shows that difference? I do not want them to say that i am abusing since i am not, my doctor is aware as i just dont want to go to a higher dose as my current dosage works well and lasts for the month. I am not sure how the hair test comes up and would appreciate any help!

Comment: No, they won't be able to see that unless you're taking way more than prescribed.

Comment: What would be way more? i am prescribed 20mg so if i take 30mg would it be ok?

Comment: Then I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: In the very unlikely event you need it, see if your doctor will write you a note saying they are aware of your occasional extra tablet.

Comment: I doubt it would actually be a problem, as others have said, but if you're worried, maybe try asking your doctor to change the prescription to be something like "20-30mg, as needed"?

Comment: I don't understand. Adderall is a controlled substance. You can't take more than what your doctor prescribes (unless you buy it from a dealer who doesn't check the prescription from your doctor).

Comment: I get enough for 2x a day, i may take 3 during the week, but i do not take any on weekends or when i am off. i may stay a couple of days without in the end of the month. I only buy from pharmacy.

Comment: Surely the test will detect the presence of adderall in your system, and the test may even be able to detect the overall level of adderall in your system, but how would the test know what your prescribed dosage is? Additionally, while the test probably can determine how much is in your system, it's doubtful to me that the test could tell how much you take on a daily basis. How would the test know that? It will determine the overall level, but I don't think it will be bale to tell how much you've taken on any given day.

Comment: Declare in advance and be up front about it, (assuming your Dr knows about the occasional 'extra' tablet and is ok with it) as you've said here, e.g. 1-10 mg twice a day and occasionally an extra 10 mg tablet with doctor's knowledge. I doubt a hair test can detect actual amount of usage or frequency with any precision, but if it did somehow show up something you would be much better to be in control of the narrative and have already declared it rather than being asked to explain about it after the fact.

Comment: I agree that they may not be able to know since it is such a small difference. But i would also assume that the level may be higher depending on how much i take. I would not know the difference between street amphetamine and Adderall. How many mg does street amphetamine have? i have done a lot of research and it seems like they would not be able to know the difference of the strengh, just whether i am an usual user (daily).

Comment: They can only detect presence or absence. Trying to determine the exact amount you’ve taken based on hair follicle would be impossible.

Comment: Professional advice: please take your medication as prescribed, especially psychotropics. They are there to help your brain regulate neurotransmitter levels and balance brain function. Taking extra one day and not taking any for a few days can seriously screw up the effectiveness of the medication and increase risk of side effects.

Comment: Just curious, what kinds of jobs require hair tests these days? I haven't heard of this since the late 90s.

Answer (score 6):

Ask your doctor. They may be able to change the words on the prescription. They should have an idea about what the testing will show and not-show.  You will be required to bring the bottle, so make sure you get a bottle with the updated label to reflect the change in prescription if it is changed.

While you are asking your doctor also ask what will happen If they give you a urine test. You never know they could give both, or the next company might give a urine test.

Comment: This is the correct course of action.  If you are worried about the fact you are actually taking 30 mg instead of 20 mg, you need to tell the doctor who prescribed you Adderall, that the prescribed dosage isn't enough.

Comment: I would also add to ask generally about taking more than prescribed. I'm sure for the doctor knowing you feel necessary and helpful to have 30mg instead of 20mg in some situations will be helpful.